# When calling HttpPost getting error: Failed to open zip archive '/system/framework/qcom.fmradio.jar': I/O Error

Tags: java, android, http-post

I want to upload file on server, i am using HttpPost to send MultipartEntity. 
But i am getting this error

Unable to open '/system/framework/qcom.fmradio.jar': No such file or directory
W/art: Failed to open zip archive '/system/framework/qcom.fmradio.jar': I/O Error

even i had given both permission Internet and write_external_storage

Here is my code

```
private void uploadVideo(String videoPath) {
    try
    {
        int SDK_INT = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
        if (SDK_INT > 8)
        {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                    .permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
            //your codes here

        }
        Log.e("upload file asynctask","-->"+videoPath);
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        File file = new File(videoPath);
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(UPLOAD_URL);

        MultipartEntityBuilder entityBuilder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
        entityBuilder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
        entityBuilder.addBinaryBody("uploadfile", file);
        // add more key/value pairs here as needed

        HttpEntity entity = entityBuilder.build();
        post.setEntity(entity);

        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = response.getEntity();

        Log.e("result--->", EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity));
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Kindly help me .. Thanks in advance

Comment: HttpClient is deprecated in Android

Comment: https://github.com/akrajilwar/Android-Image-Upload/blob/master/app/src/main/java/org/snowcorp/imageupload/MainActivity.java

Comment: Thanks @NaveenTamrakar